# What happens if two Divination Wizards try to affect a roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, divination

Does this interact like Lucky, wherein both Portent rolls cancel each other out and the original, untampered roll is used, or would the diviner that replaces the roll later, override the other that tried to replace the roll earlier?